# Where should I ask career transition questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about which type of work experience is more valuable.  A lot of similar questions are asked on the Programmers stack exchange, but all of them are closed and the faq there directs you to post those questions here.  I posted the question here and it was closed almost immediately.

My question is "I'm considering job A doing A' type work and job B doing B' type work; which work experience is more valuable in terms of salary growth?"

If I can't ask that on the Programmers stack or here (where the programmers stack directed me); where should I ask it?

I would ask this on the meta, but since I'm new to the site, it won't let me.

Comment: I've voted to close with the reason "belongs on meta". If enough people agree, it'll automatically move the post there (I believe).

Comment: Be aware that the answer may well be "nowhere on Stack Exchange".

Comment: Keep it generalized as possible so the principles discussed in the answers can be useful to as many people as possible.

Comment: [Chat] is a great resource. Are you able to use it? You have enough rep I think from Stack Overflow so you should have access.

Comment: Is there a specific room that you think would be a good place for this type of question?

Comment: @Damien you could try [The Water Cooler](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), which is this site's chat, or [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) which is for programmers.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Such questions are often problematic for several reasons.

- Your experience can be valued very differently by different employers. One might pay you more for experience in A while the other values you more for experience B.
- It's often hard to compare. In many businesses the experience value of "A type experience" doesn't just depend on what job title you held and for how long, but also on what specializations you had, how successful you were and the reputation of who you worked for.
- The difference becomes even greater when looking at your personal qualifications. It might be better to take a less-paying job you are qualified for so you can impress your superiors with your success than a higher-paying job you are unqualified for and which will set you up for failure.
- Even when the previous points do not apply: The work market is constantly changing. A skill which is in high demand now might be in low demand in a few years. So any advise you get now might turn out to be bad advise in the future.
- Work experience is often only a minor factor when it comes to salary expectations. There are a lot of other things which decide how much salary you are worth, like how you can sell yourself to potential employees.
- It's often a very localized question which only applies to one person. That makes it not very helpful for future visitors.

Comment: These reasons are exactly why a back/forth is required for any question like this. hence chat/discussion boards are better, because the core questions there require a lot of "what about X?" types of clarifications.